# Multiplayer minecraft problems on ps3. Invisible players

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

When I was playing online with my friends on the ps3 (minecraft) I would randomly glitch out and teleport to in the middle of nowhere and get teleprompter back... half of the players turn invisible. particle effects are on, and I didn't see any. I tried reseting my ps3 and coming back to thevworld, but it would just happen again... anyone know what's happening? Is it my connection?

Answer (score -2):

It might be your connection. Sometimes if one of the players has a less powerful wifi connection then the others then sometimes it can move the player to somewhere it wasn't. Either that, or your PS3 may be glitching.